# Proof that bipartite graph has perfect matching if and only if zero sub-matrix is not included

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

How to proof that

Binary matrix of $n\times n$ dimension contains $n$ ones none of which two lie in the same row or column, if and only if matrix that represents graph doesn't contain zero sub-matrix $M$ of dimension $k\times (n-k+1)$ for  $k=1,...,n$. Columns and rows of sub-matrix don't have to be subsequent column/rows of the output matrix.

Comment: What do you already know about perfect matchings in bipartite graphs? Which of those tools have you already tried applying to this problem?

Comment: I know that regular bipartite graph always has perfect matching.  I know that choosing n ones from n x n matrix none of which two lie in the same row or column is equivalent to find perfect matching in bipartite graph. I also know how to use Hall theorem.

Comment: Hint: show that the condition "there is no $k\times(n+1-k)$ sub-matrix of zeroes" is equivalent to the Hall condition.

Comment: @MikeEarnest still no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hall's marriage theorem says that a bipartite graph, with parts $A$ and $B$ has a perfect matching iff the Hall condition holds:

> **Hall condition:** For every subset $S$ of $A$ with $k$ vertices, the number of vertices in $B$ adjacent to some vertex in $S$ is at least $k$.

Let's say the rows of the matrix correspond to vertices of $A$, and the columns are vertices of $B$.

Suppose that the Hall condition fails. This means there exist $k$ rows whose neighbors only consist of $k-1$ or fewer columns. But then the $k\times (n+1-k)$ sub-matrix, defined by those rows and the columns which are *not* adjacent to those rows, is filled with zeroes.

Similarly, if you find a $k\times (n+1-k)$ sub-matrix of zeroes, then those $k$ rows will only be adjacent to $k-1$ columns, so the Hall condition fails.